# Python How to re-assign a static variable value of a python class with a return value of method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to declare a static variable inside the class. I am trying to add a return value of a code inside a function.

The return value is assigned to the static variable inside the class but when i try to create an object of the class and access the static variable value from another class, it still returns the old value.

```
class Login(Base):
      token = ''
      def run(self):
           token=keystone.get_raw_token_from_identity_service('http://localhost:35357/v3,
username=username,                                             user_domain_name='default,                                         password=passwrd,                                                                      project_name=project,                                                     project_domain_name='default')

      def auth_token(self,token):
          self.token = token
          return self.token
```

In another class, i am trying to call the static variable but it always prints the initial value declared in the first class i.e. token = ''

```
      credentials = Login(Base)
      print(type(credentials.auth_token.__func__))
      print(hasattr(credentials,'token'))
      print(credentials.token)"""
```

Comment: If you really want the `token` to be the same across all instances of `Login`, then refer to it as `Login.token` rather than `self.token`.  However, are you sure that's the behaviour you want?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that's not the problem

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I wouldn't know, I _hate_ non-constant static members

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well bully for you; maybe don't weigh in on them, then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I mean: variable static data members is rarely a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you make auth_token a @classmethod, it will behave the way you want

```
  @classmethod 
  def auth_token(cls, token):
      cls.token = token
      return cls.token
```

I'm not sure I love the design, but that's your affair.

EDIT: Here's an example of this code in action, in response to comments:

```
>>> class Login(object):
...   token = ""
...   @classmethod 
...   def auth_token(cls, token):
...       cls.token = token
...       return cls.token
... 
>>> l = Login()
>>> l2 = Login()
>>> l.token
''
>>> l2.token
''
>>> l.auth_token("foo")
'foo'
>>> l2.token
'foo'
>>>
```

Comment: Jon, i made the changes as above, but still i can see the old value in my class Create i.e. 2nd class.

Comment: `class Create(Login):
    """Create the virtual Instance or Instances"""

    def run(self):
        credentials = Login(Base)
        print(type(credentials.auth_token.__func__))
        print(hasattr(credentials,'token'))
        print(getattr(credentials,'token'))
        print(type(credentials.token))
        print 'Create virtual instance class!'
        print 'You supplied the following options:', dumps(self.options, indent=2, sort_keys=True)`

Comment: The above code prints this output, <type 'function'>
True

<type 'str'>
Create virtual instance class!

Comment: I am able to see the type(credentials.token) as <str> but how to print the value of token, can you please help.

Comment: @Kalyan I'm not sure what that code has to do with your question.

Comment: I need to call the value stored in token into the other class, i need to print the value of token.

Comment: Jon, i have implemented your code. I have a base class or parent class where i added the method and in Login class i am replacing the value of token. Now, l.auth_token("foo") shows me the new value. But, i ran into another problem, i have a different class called as Create, here i am creating an object instance of Login(Base) but when i print the token, it shows me empty value i.e. the initial empty value of token static variable. is it possible to pass the l.auth_token replaced value to the Create class so that i can use the replace value in Create class.